# check how much network traffic is consumed by each process

Tags: macos, networking, network-analysis

I want to determine programmatically **how much** network traffic is consumed by each process.

I would prefer for a crossplatform solution but I guess this is not possible, so I am searching for a solution which works on MacOSX right now.

The solution should be lightweight. I want to run it in background and it should analyse all running processes.

(Stupid disclaimer: As I am asking on Stackoverflow, I am implying by that that I am asking for programmatic solutions here. The [same question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/205199/macosx-how-much-network-traffic-by-each-app) means something different.)

Answer (score 2):

nethogs

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
sudo nethogs
```

nethogs uses libpcap. To get the sources on Ubuntu and learn from that:

```
apt-get source nethogs
```

In particular the decpcap.c file is probably relevant.

And these links might be helpful:

- http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=pcap
- http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html
- http://libpcap.darwinports.com/  (Mac pcap install instructions)

Comment: I know this is extremely old, but, as an OSX user looking for an alt. to nethogs, this answer is extremely unhelpful.

Comment: @MikeBell you might try this: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3687564 (nettop)